# Op-Amp circuit output analysis trouble

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, 741-opamp

What is the output voltage Vo of the OPAMP circuit given below?

[image]

**Attempt at solution:** THE ANSWER IS GIVEN: 6V, but according to me as the positive terminal is grounded the negative terminal will be virtually grounded (0V), from ohm's law (applying to the two series resistance) it is expected that Vo is 0V!

I don't know where I am getting wrong!

Comment: OMG where did that circuit come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> THE ANSWER IS GIVEN: 6V

And that answer is wrong. As drawn, the + input of the opmap is **grounded**

The voltages 1V, 2V, 3V **do nothing**.

The rest of the circuit will have as solution \$V_O\$ = 0 V as that is the only valid solution for such a feedback circuit.

So as Tony suggests:

- the answer is wrong

or

- the circuit has been drawn in the wrong way.

You're not wrong!

The question and/or answer are wrong!

Kudos to you for spotting that.

Answer (score 4):

Either it’s a dumb drawing or a trick question.

Disconnect erroneous gnd on Vin+ and recompute.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing is wrong.
No GND on the non inverting input.